# Quick way to combine a bunch of commits together (git)

Tags: git, git-merge, rebase

I have branches master and feature.

Feature has about 20 commits ahead of master.

I want to squash all commits together so when I merge I have one commit. Is there a way to do this with one command? I know I could do an interactive rebase; but I am looking for a command that makes this easy.

Comment: Do you want to keep feature branch's commit history, or get rid of it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes!

On the master branch:

`git merge --squash feature-branch`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
git rebase -i {revision-number} 
git rebase --interactive {revision-number}
```

Where `-i` means that you are going to enter into the interactive mode. You specify the revision from which you want the merge to occur.

After entering the interactive mode you will select for the first one the `pick` option and for the others `squash`. This way you will combine the multiple commits from feature branch into a single one. Then you can do:

```
git checkout master
git merge feature
```

Here is a great explanation:

http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html